# How can I specify the volumes quota?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

How can I specify the volumes quota with docker-compose?

In the [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) I can't find any quota or size options for volumes.

Comment: Should be `driver_opts`, but this will heavily depend on your storage driver and backing filesystem. You'll likely want to lookup the details on Linux quota support, especially with bind mounts, for your specific distribution and version.

Comment: @BMitch Ok. So there's no docker specific disk quota?

Comment: Docker can be thought of as an interface to underlying tooling. Volume storage in particular is dependent on the underlying filesystem, which is why the first linked question referred to things like zfs and btrfs.